# Matlab, find index of minimum value with the condition that it must be negative

Tags: arrays, matlab, find, min

In a given array, I need to find the index of the minimum value in an array, but only if it is negative.

For example : `[1, 2, 3, 4]` would return no indices

and `[1, 4, -7, -2]` would return `3`

I was thinking that it must be simple with the `find()` command, but I couldn't figure out how to use it for this specific situation.

Comment: I discovered it myself when I tried your question. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the input matrix is `A`, this should do the trick:

```
find(A==min(A) & A<0)
```

For example:

```
>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
>> B = [1, 4, -7, -2];
>> find(A==min(A) & A<0)

ans =

   Empty matrix: 1-by-0

>> find(B==min(B) & B<0)

ans =

     3
```

Comment: I initially posted a function, then came up with: `find(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)eq(x,min(A(sign(A) == -1))),A,'UniformOutput',false)))` . LOL, sometimes you need to take a step back and think about things before you start coding...

Comment: @jucestain: Yeah. :D It happens to the best of us at times.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is about 3 times slower than the solution posted by Ben Voigt, just something to consider.

Comment: @Dan Depends on what OP is doing. If his implementation needs the function above once or twice it should be fine. Implementing Ben's solution will require either a separate function file or a function appended to the end of another function file, which will limit the scope of that function anyway. I also just tic toc'd this solution for a 100k vector and it took 0.001 seconds. IMO its much better to go with the clear and concise solution (as above) and worry about optimization later, but ultimately it depends on OP's problem.

Comment: @jucestain I was just pointing it out as it's worth considering. But you don't need a separate function at all. It may not be one line but there is no reason why it can't go in the code exactly where this solution does.

Comment: @Dan You're right... My bad. For some reason this question messing with me :P.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, throwing everything into one complicated vector expression isn't optimal.

In this instance, I expect it to be much faster to avoid a call to `find`.

```
function [i] = most_negative_index(x)
   [mn, i] = min(x);
   if mn >= 0
       i = [];
   end
end
```